# How to use the Twitter API to get banned tweets?

Tags: web-scraping, twitter, twitterapi-python

I used Twitter API for Tweets lookup. I have one question that if some tweets were already banned/ reported or blocked, is there some ways to scrape/track the original content based on Twitter API?

> https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/quick-start

Our aim is to find these banned messages and analyze them. I would appreciate any suggestions or methods.

Answer (score 0):

If Tweets are not public or they have been deleted, then they cannot be retrieved via the Twitter API, no.